# Populate a partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I feel stupid asking this but I cant seem to get a partial view rendering in a page.

I have created a partial view that im trying to load into my index page. I have called my pv _BusinessDetails basically its a view that returns some customer data.

My pv looks like

```
@model MyMVC.Models.BusinessModel
<div class="grid">

<div class="grid-header">
<div class="gh-l"></div>
    <div class="gh-m">Business Details</div>
<div class="gh-r"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-row">
     <label class="labelBold">Busines Name</label>
     <label>@Model.BusinesName</label>
</div>

</div>
```

From my index page I am trying to call the pv using

```
    @Html.Partial("_BusinessDetails")
```

which fails so if I add

```
@Html.Partial("_BusinessDetails",new MyMVC.Models.BusinessModel())
```

The partial view is loaded however with no data as the controller isn't been hit. In my controller I have tried

```
public ActionResult _BusinessDetails()
  {
      return PartialView("_BusinessDetails");
  }

 public PartialViewResult _BusinessDetails()
    {
        return PartialView("_BusinessDetails");
    }
```

However neither of them are hit. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering a partial view and passing a view model, that view model should already be populated.  No controllers/action methods are invoked when using `@Html.Partial()`.

Since you are using this strongly-typed partial view on your home page, consider building its view model in your `HomeController`'s `Index()` method. Is your index page strongly-typed as well? If so, you can add your partial view's view model as a property of your index page's view model, and pass that when calling `@Html.Partial()`.

On your index page, it would look something like:

```
@model MyMVC.Models.IndexViewModel
<!-- some HTML here -->
@Html.RenderPartial("_BusinessDetails", Model.BusinessModel)
```

If your index page is not strongly-typed, you can use the `ViewBag` object or you can strongly-type it to `MyMVC.Models.BusinessModel` and use `@Html.RenderPartial("_BusinessDetails", Model)` (which, while simple, could cause confusion).

Rachel Appel has a nice [blog post](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/), as does [Mike Brind](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels), if you would like more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky. I've had success with using a model on the main view as a container object:

```
class MainPageModel {
    public BusinessDetailModel BusinessDetails { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

and then just passing the whole model like `@Html.Partial("_BusinessDetails", Model)` to my partial views.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote this,

```
@Html.Partial("_BusinessDetails",new MyMVC.Models.BusinessModel())
```

The data is not loaded as your model is empty, so before passing model *BusinessModel*,fill it before.